# How can I define this python function?

Tags: python-3.x

```
from mailmerge import MailMerge
with MailMerge('template.docx') as document:

    document.merge(
        NB_Effective_Date = '1',
        NB_EffectiveDate_PlusOne = NB_EffectiveDate +'1'
    )

    document.write('666.docx')
```

After I run this code, it say NB_Effective_Date is not defined. I think i have already defined it as a string.

Comment: You are passing in a parameter `NB_Effective_Date = '1'` to the function `document.merge`, you are not declaring a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
document.merge(
    NB_Effective_Date = '1',
    NB_EffectiveDate_PlusOne = NB_EffectiveDate +'1'
)
```

You are passing to the `merge()` function two arguments: NB_Effective_Date and NB_EffectiveDate_PlusOne.  That's OK.  But the value of NB_EffectiveDate_PlusOne your passing is...what exactly?  You've written `NB_EffectiveDate +'1'` but indeed `NB_EffectiveDate` is not a variable you've defined, it is actually the name of another argument you're passing, which is a name that `merge()` can use, but not you.

You may want this instead:

```
effdate = '1'
document.merge(
    NB_Effective_Date = effdate,
    NB_EffectiveDate_PlusOne = effdate + '1'
)
```

Next you'll probably realize `'1' + '1'` is somewhat nonsensical, unless you really want `'11'`.  You'll need to think more about what you really want there.